# MYSQL Inner Join with Criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Command and it looks like this

```
UPDATE Variance as VAR INNER JOIN receiving as REV ON (VAR.ItemCode = REV.ItemCode)
SET VAR.Receiving = REV.QtyPack * REV.PCS + REV.QtyStan;
```

and its working perfectly.
now my question here is how can I apply this criteria to mysql command?

1.Receiving.Date is Between 2 Dates

2.Receiving.Status = "Posted"

3.If Receiving.QtyPack and Receiving.QtyStan = "0" or "NULL" then Var.Receiving will become "0"

I hope you dont downvote this.
Please do not hesitate to ask question or clarification and I will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add the conditions directly into the query:

```
UPDATE Variance VAR INNER JOIN
       receiving REV
       ON VAR.ItemCode = REV.ItemCode
    SET VAR.Receiving = COALESCE(REV.QtyPack * REV.PCS + REV.QtyStan, 0)
    WHERE rev.Status = 'Posted' AND
          rev.date between $date1 and $date2;
```

The `COALESCE()` converts `NULL` values to `0`, which is part of the third condition.

Comment: TYSM for help its already working now, I can only accept it after 3 minutes. Sir may I ask one question lets say i will add more criterian then I will just add "and" and criteria

Comment: @ShadowFiend ... Yes, you would add more conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: TYSM  really great help

Comment: Sir I try it but theres no zero populated